# Construct matrix object from list of data (separated by empty line)

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

I have a file which has scientific data expressed in scientific notation. The format is following where always bunch of 6 rows of numbers appear together,

```
  4.748257444721457E-004    
 -4.058788876602824E-006    
 -1.494658656964534E-004    
  4.686186383664201E-006    
  3.840708360798801E-006    

-3.237680480600605E-005
-3.237680480600605E-005
5.290165586028430E-005
-1.312378015891650E-005
-9.693957759497108E-006
3.184131106435972E-005
```

I am trying to construct a matrix (in python) out of the above to the form as  shown below;

```
  4.748257444721457E-004     -3.237680480600605E-005
 -4.058788876602824E-006      5.290165586028430E-005
 -1.494658656964534E-004     -1.312378015891650E-005
  4.686186383664201E-006     -9.693957759497108E-006
  3.840708360798801E-006      3.184131106435972E-005
```

I am wondering if such construction as a matrix is possible in python (which can then be used for further mathematical analysis) ?

---

I tried this approach.

Convert the numbers to decimal then make a matrix using bash script then load in python as txt.

However, I do not want to get rid of the floating numbers (causes loss of precision), hence I am thinking of a loop approach to generate this matrix. The real data set has 54x54 values.

Comment: it is easily possible. what if you have 90 elements in the list, what is your expected dimension for the matrix? by the way, what did you try to achieve this? show your effort.

Comment: The precise answer to your question would be "yes, it is possible". This is probably not the answer you were looking for. There are many ways to parse text files and create matrices. In order to get a better answer you may want to ask about a specific problem with the approach you tried so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may help you.

```
import numpy as np

matrix = []
row = []
with open("input.txt") as f:
    for line in f:
        line = line.rstrip('\n')
        if not line:
            if len(row) != 0:
                matrix.append(row)
            row = []
            continue
        row.append(float(line))

if len(row) != 0:
    matrix.append(row)

matrix = np.asarray(matrix).T
print(matrix)
```

It prints:

```
[[  4.74825744e-04  -3.23768048e-05]
 [ -4.05878888e-06  -3.23768048e-05]
 [ -1.49465866e-04   5.29016559e-05]
 [  4.68618638e-06  -1.31237802e-05]
 [  3.84070836e-06  -9.69395776e-06]
 [  3.84070836e-06   3.18413111e-05]]
```

You can also print the matrix by iterating through rows and columns.

```
for row in range(matrix.shape[0]):
    for column in range(matrix.shape[1]):
        print(matrix[row][column], end=' ')
    print()
```

It prints:

```
0.000474825744472 -3.2376804806e-05 
-4.0587888766e-06 -3.2376804806e-05 
-0.000149465865696 5.29016558603e-05 
4.68618638366e-06 -1.31237801589e-05 
3.8407083608e-06 -9.6939577595e-06 
3.8407083608e-06 3.18413110644e-05
```

You can also print with precision in scientific format.

```
print('{:.4e}'.format(matrix[row][column]), end=' ')
```

The input file - `input.txt` contains:

```
4.748257444721457e-004
-4.058788876602824e-006
-1.494658656964534e-004
4.686186383664201e-006
3.840708360798801e-006
3.840708360798801e-006

-3.237680480600605e-005
-3.237680480600605e-005
5.290165586028430e-005
-1.312378015891650e-005
-9.693957759497108e-006
3.184131106435972e-005
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I just realized I made another mistake while trying, the `E-001`  is different from  `e-001` and causes it to appear as string ! Still learning. :-)

Comment: @ankit7540 no no, `e` or `E` doesn't matter. When you will print, it prints `e` but for input, both `e` and `E` works fine. please don't get confuse.

Comment: I see. Then probably spaces  before each number was the issue giving error as `ValueError: could not convert string to float:
`. I then removed all spaces and also changed `E` to `e`. From the documentation I see that both `E` and `e` are ok. Thanks for correcting.